# Is it possible to deploy Firebase Cloud Function via API REST? Would it work if I deploy using gcp cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have to deploy several Firebase projects as they are sold, and I'm struggling with API REST endpoints in order to be able to get the job done. Sometimes, as it is for enabling and using cloud storage, I had to start the process in gcloud api rest (create the bucket) and finish in firebase api rest (add firebase). Besides, I couldn't enable Firebase default bucket, which ends with appspot.com and requires domain verification. It is quite confusing.
Now I have to deploy the project's cloud functions, but there is no endpoint for that in Firebase API Management documentation. I am assuming I should deploy via google cloud api, but I'm not sure whether or not it is the right path to take.

Can anyone help me?

I read all Firebase API rest documentation and couldn't figure out a way of doing that.

Comment: In Google Cloud, everything is managed and deployed with REST or gRPC APIs. Therefore the answer to your question is `YES`. Questions on Stack Overflow need to be focussed, show one problem, code, errors, etc.

Comment: You can read the CLI code to see how it does a deployment. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks man! Sorry about the way I made my question.